# Spyder and virtual environments

Tags: python, anaconda

I am approaching the use of python, i was wondering if it is correct to install  Spyder in the 'root' environment and then point to other environments when coding on a project.
Is it correct or it is better to install a Spyder for each environment?
Thanks

Comment: This might be an opinion based question. Unless someone has good technical reasons to suggest the opposite. However, what I do is, using Anaconda and install Spyder in every Environment I create. Just to be sure that everything is clear and independent from the rest.

Comment: I saw that using Spyder from the root environment doesn't pick new packages that I install with pip